# Powershell script to zip users home folder and move it to share drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to move users home folder to share drive who has left the company but before that I want to `ZIP` it using `powershell script`. Could you please suggest me or write me quick `powershell script` which `ZIPs` the folder and move to share drive creating a same folder name with zip file also same name in destination folder. For instance if source folder is `C:\test` and destination `is \\share\test\`

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: "or write me quick powershell script" ...sweet :D

Comment: And just in case somebody takes this up, which version of PS did you actually want this written for?

Comment: No one here will write your code for you, however these links should be helpful in working it out for yourself.  

[ZIP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/09/use-powershell-to-create-zip-archive-of-folder/)

[Copy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx)

If you give that a shot and are still having trouble post back with what you've attempted and what errors you are getting and we will be happy to help you work through them.

Comment: Function Zip
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$zipFile
        ,
        [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )
 $CurDir = Get-Location
 Set-Location "C:\Program Files\7-zip\"
 .\7z.exe A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
 Set-Location $CurDir
}
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "60"
$TargetFolder = "\\share\test\"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
$Files
Zip \\share\test\TEST.zip $Files
#If(Test-Path \\share\test\TEST.zip)
#{
#    Remove-Item $files
#}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to zip a folder:
[Creating a zipped/compressed folder in Windows using Powershell or the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021879/creating-a-zipped-compressed-folder-in-windows-using-powershell-or-the-command-l)

Creating a new folder is simple:

```
New-Item c:\folder -type directory
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx

And moving a file is also very simple too:

```
Move-Item c:\source\file.zip c:\destination
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx

Comment: Hi JamesFunction Zip
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$zipFile
        ,
        [string[]]$toBeZipped
    )
 $CurDir = Get-Location
 Set-Location "C:\Program Files\7-zip\"
 .\7z.exe A -tzip $zipFile $toBeZipped | Out-Null
 Set-Location $CurDir
}
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = "60"
$TargetFolder = "\\share\test\"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}
$Files
Zip \\share\test\TEST.zip $Files
#If(Test-Path \\share\test\TEST.zip)
#{
#    Remove-Item $files
#}